# Constructing a Tapir Endpoint from a URL String that Includes query parameters

Tags: scala, tapir

I need to use an API that returns a url to the next page in its response.
My code is written in a way that I need to construct tapir endpoint to make http call.
But I don't see a way to transform url string into `EndpointInput`. The url contains query parameters and `.in(string)` doesn't seem to be able to handle it.

What is the correct way to transform a URL string, which contains query parameters, into a Tapir EndpointInput?

Comment: Sounds like you're using Tapir in a weird way in the 1st place IMHO. Although it's able to generate client code from an endpoint definition, the endpoint definition is supposed to be written by the producer of the service.

Comment: If you really have to, you probably need to interpret the URL and detect its query parameters and path parameters to generate the corresponding `EndpointInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [Tapir](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir) works in that way.

If you check the [docs](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/index.html), you will see the following definitions

> #### [Tapir](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/index.html#tapir)
>
> Declarative, type-safe web endpoints library.
>
> #### [Intro](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/index.html#intro)
>
> With tapir, you can describe HTTP API endpoints as immutable Scala values. Each endpoint can contain a number of input and output parameters.
>
> #### [Why tapir?](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/index.html#why-tapir)
>
> - **type-safety**: compile-time guarantees, develop-time completions, read-time information
> - **declarative**: separate the shape of the endpoint (the “what”), from the server logic (the “how”)
>
> #### [Goals of the project](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/goals.html#goals-of-the-project)
>
> - based purely on case class-based, immutable and reusable data structures
> - reasonably type safe: only, and as much types to safely generate the server/client/docs

An **endpoint** built using **tapir** looks like

```scala
val endpointDefinition: Endpoint = 
  endpoint
    .delete.         // EndpointInput.FixedMethod
    .in(             // EndpointInput
         "api"       // String ==> EndpointInput.FixedPath
         /           // EndpointInput.Pair
         "v1"        // String ==> EndpointInput.FixedPath
         /           // EndpointInput.Pair
         "noun"      // String ==> EndpointInput.FixedPath
         / path[Int] // EndpointInput.PathCapture
     )
     .out(           // EndpointOutput
       stringBody    // EndpointIO.Body
     )
```

All the `String`s will be transformed to `EndpointInput.FixedPath` because there is an [implicit def stringToPath](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/v1.6.0/core/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/Tapir.scala#L22).

Then you have the case class [Endpoint](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/v1.6.0/core/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/Endpoint.scala#L43)

```scala
case class Endpoint[SECURITY_INPUT, INPUT, ERROR_OUTPUT, OUTPUT, -R](
    securityInput: EndpointInput[SECURITY_INPUT],
    input: EndpointInput[INPUT],
    errorOutput: EndpointOutput[ERROR_OUTPUT],
    output: EndpointOutput[OUTPUT],
    info: EndpointInfo
) extends EndpointInputsOps 
     with // ...
```

As you can see, you have the `Endpoint` class which is the definition of the endpoint with some attributes that contains info about the inputs and outputs. The [in](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/v1.6.0/core/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/Endpoint.scala#L119) method comes from the trait [EndpointInputsOps](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/v1.6.0/core/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/Endpoint.scala#L103) which is mixed in the `Endpoint` class and that's why you can call that method.

From there, you can generate a **client**, a **server** and the **docs** from **scala** code at **compile-time** using the interpreter you need such as `akka-http`, `zio-http`, `Vert.x`, `OpenAPI`, `AsyncAPI`.

You can also [Generate Endpoint definitions from OpenAPI](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/generator/sbt-openapi-codegen.html), but again it works at compile-time.

---

In your question you said:

> I need to use an API that returns a url to the next page in its response

Which means, in some part of your project there will be something like

```scala
val response = service.execute(params...)
val url = response.nextUrl
val result = client.sendRequest(url)
```

The url is returned in runtime, mean while tapir works at compile-time.

---

If you know the URL at compilation time, you could use some parser (maybe with a regex is enough). Which doesn't make any sense parse a known string to then generate an endpoint definition